# How to get user country name by google signin API?

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I am new in android developement. I am developing mobile app. In this app, It is need to user country, Plz help to me, how to get user country when user sign in by google account. I am wasting much more time, but did not get any solution.

```
Scope myScope = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read");
    Scope myScope2 = new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME);
    Scope myScope3 = new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE); //get name and id

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(myScope, myScope2, myScope3)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();



mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient //this is the line of the error
                .Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this,(GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La conexión alcliente api de Google ha fallado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                //.addApi(Plus.API)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
                .build();
```

---

```
 GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        System.out.println("Display Name:="+acct.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println("Display Name:="+acct.getEmail());
        System.out.println(""+ acct.getGivenName());
        System.out.println(""+acct.getFamilyName());
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but Shutting down Google+ and login APIs for consumer (personal) accounts on April 2, 2019

Comment: Where are you heard about this? Is there any link or anything reference, plz share us

Comment: Thanks for sharing info, but it is going shut down because of deprecated error. It will available "plus.me", "plus.login", "plus.profile.emails.read"